# Crosstab crystal report text color

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm trying to change the text color based on a condition on crystal report cross tab but it changes color of entire column when that condition is met instead of changing color of that particular cell, the whole column color is changed.

Formula:

```
if({VDetailedDataSheet.obtained}='A') then  CrRed  else CrBlack
```

[image]

Second record that is "23" should be black according to formula.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is to Open your cross-tab report, then right click on the cell and select Format Field. Then navigate to the Font tab, and choose the Color formula editor and type:

```
if (CurrentFieldValue='A') then crRed else crBlack
```

Answer (score 0):

I used CurrentFieldValue instead of the filed name and it worked.